# MVC 3 - ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

I am using RegisterRoutes method in Global file to route user url to actual url.

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog", 
                "blog/dp/{id}", 
                 new { controller ="Blog", action = "Details" });
```

As you might have guessed, **Blog** is the controller and **Details** is its action.

So the problem is that the following code does not generate my desire URL which has **dp** word in its url.
By the way, I don't want to change my Action Name.

```
@Html.ActionLink( "headline", "Details", "Blog", new { id="1200" }, null )
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Does the url route correctly?  If you enter the url `http://site/blog/dp/1200` does it route to the correct page?  And do you have any other routes that map to the same controller?  It might help to include all your routes in your question.

Comment: Yup, it routes to the correct page ;) my problem is that the actionlink generate this "http://site/Blog/Details?id=1200"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a RouteLink instead of using an ActionLink. In a RouteLink you can explicitly pass your route name:

```
@Html.RouteLink("headline", "Blog", new { controller = "Blog", action = "Details" })
```

More about RouteLink method can be found in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460117.aspx). Reordering routes can do the job but that's a rather fragile mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The ActionLink may be using a different route from what you are providing in the question.  Do you have any routes declared before this one?

The routes are matched in the order that you provide them.  So, for instance, if you had something like:

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog", 
                "blog/dp",       // {id} is not provided in this one
                 new { controller ="Blog", action = "Details" });
```

declared before this route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog", 
                "blog/dp/{id}", 
                 new { controller ="Blog", action = "Details" });
```

The first route would be matched first and you would see /blog/dp/?id=1200 instead of /blog/dp/1200.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my MapRoutes work fine and my problem is that actionlink cannot be used in mentioned scenario.BTW, I know that I can detour this problem by using <a> tag.